# Bootstrap navbar dropdown list not working properly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the dropdown list in the navigation bar. It was working properly last night but i don't know what happened the bootstrap stopped working only for the dropdown list. Please help me out of this.Bootstrap file link is working properly because its working for the whole page but not working for navbar dropdowns only.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand name-style" href="#"><span style="color: #4dc47d;">Abasyn Univeristy Islamabad Campus</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Home
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="index.php"> Home </a></li>
          <li><a href="about.php"> About</a></li>
          <li><a href="history.php"> History </a></li>
     <li><a href="vision.php"> Vision & Mission </a></li>
          <li><a href="objectives.php">  Objectives </a></li>
     <li><a href="messages.php">   Messages </a></li>

    </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Programs
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="undergrad.php">  Undergraduate </a></li>
          <li><a href="graduate.php"> Graduate </a></li>
          <li><a href="departments.php"> Departments</a></li>
     <li> <a href="policies.php"> Rules and Policies </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admission
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="addmission.php">  Admission Overview </a></li>
          <li><a href="financialAid.php"> Financial Aid </a></li>
          <li><a href="Scholarship.php"> Scholarships </a></li>
     <li><a href="fee_Structure.php">  Fee Structure </a></li>
     <li><a href="addmission_procedure.php">  Admission Procedure </a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Faculty
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="electrical_engineering.php">  Department of Electrical Engineering </a></li>
          <li><a href="computing.php"> Department of Computing & Technology </a></li>
          <li><a href="civil_enginnering.php"> Department of Civil Engineering </a></li>
     <li><a href="management_sciences.php"> Department of Management Science </a></li>
     <li><a href="life_sciences.php">  Department of Life Science </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Research
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="projects.php">  Projects </a></li>
          <li><a href="publications.php"> Publications </a></li>
          <li><a href="conference.php"> Abasyn Intl. Conference </a></li>
     <li><a href="journal.php"> Journal of Social Sciences </a></li>
    </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="activities.php">  Activities & Clubs </a></li>
          <li><a href="http://abasynisb.edu.pk/pdf/Handbook-final-draft.pdf"> Student Handbook</a></li>
          <li><a href="community.php"> Community Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="student_schedules.php"> Student Schedules </a></li>
          <li><a href="digital_library.php"> Digital Library </a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Learning Management System </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Center of M & E
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">About the Center</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">OBE at AUIC</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Software System - TLS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"> Research and Analysis</a></li>

    </ul>
      </li>

 </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnmI.png) is the output

Comment: Have you changed some css or anything else ??

Comment: I just made a code snippet of your code, and it seems to work to me (doesn't it?). I did add the `<link>` and `<script>`'s of bootstrap. Maybe you added them wrong or in wrong order? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the css and js you have used. If you add these Cdn will solve your problem

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The solution:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand name-style" href="#"><span style="color: #4dc47d;">Abasyn Univeristy Islamabad Campus</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Home
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="index.php"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php"> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="history.php"> History </a></li>
                <li><a href="vision.php"> Vision & Mission </a></li>
      <li><a href="objectives.php">  Objectives </a></li>
                <li><a href="messages.php">   Messages </a></li>

            </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Programs
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="undergrad.php">  Undergraduate </a></li>
      <li><a href="graduate.php"> Graduate </a></li>
      <li><a href="departments.php"> Departments</a></li>
                <li> <a href="policies.php"> Rules and Policies </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admission
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="addmission.php">  Admission Overview </a></li>
      <li><a href="financialAid.php"> Financial Aid </a></li>
      <li><a href="Scholarship.php"> Scholarships </a></li>
                <li><a href="fee_Structure.php">  Fee Structure </a></li>
                <li><a href="addmission_procedure.php">  Admission Procedure </a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Faculty
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="electrical_engineering.php">  Department of Electrical Engineering </a></li>
      <li><a href="computing.php"> Department of Computing & Technology </a></li>
      <li><a href="civil_enginnering.php"> Department of Civil Engineering </a></li>
                <li><a href="management_sciences.php"> Department of Management Science </a></li>
                <li><a href="life_sciences.php">  Department of Life Science </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Research
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="projects.php">  Projects </a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.php"> Publications </a></li>
      <li><a href="conference.php"> Abasyn Intl. Conference </a></li>
                <li><a href="journal.php"> Journal of Social Sciences </a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="activities.php">  Activities & Clubs </a></li>
      <li><a href="http://abasynisb.edu.pk/pdf/Handbook-final-draft.pdf"> Student Handbook</a></li>
      <li><a href="community.php"> Community Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="student_schedules.php"> Student Schedules </a></li>
      <li><a href="digital_library.php"> Digital Library </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> Learning Management System </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Center of M & E
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">About the Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OBE at AUIC</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software System - TLS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Research and Analysis</a></li>

            </ul>
  </li>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand name-style" href="#"><span style="color: #4dc47d;">Abasyn Univeristy Islamabad Campus</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Home
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="index.php"> Home </a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php"> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="history.php"> History </a></li>
                <li><a href="vision.php"> Vision & Mission </a></li>
      <li><a href="objectives.php">  Objectives </a></li>
                <li><a href="messages.php">   Messages </a></li>

            </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Programs
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="undergrad.php">  Undergraduate </a></li>
      <li><a href="graduate.php"> Graduate </a></li>
      <li><a href="departments.php"> Departments</a></li>
                <li> <a href="policies.php"> Rules and Policies </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admission
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="addmission.php">  Admission Overview </a></li>
      <li><a href="financialAid.php"> Financial Aid </a></li>
      <li><a href="Scholarship.php"> Scholarships </a></li>
                <li><a href="fee_Structure.php">  Fee Structure </a></li>
                <li><a href="addmission_procedure.php">  Admission Procedure </a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Faculty
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="electrical_engineering.php">  Department of Electrical Engineering </a></li>
      <li><a href="computing.php"> Department of Computing & Technology </a></li>
      <li><a href="civil_enginnering.php"> Department of Civil Engineering </a></li>
                <li><a href="management_sciences.php"> Department of Management Science </a></li>
                <li><a href="life_sciences.php">  Department of Life Science </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Research
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="projects.php">  Projects </a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.php"> Publications </a></li>
      <li><a href="conference.php"> Abasyn Intl. Conference </a></li>
                <li><a href="journal.php"> Journal of Social Sciences </a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Students
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="activities.php">  Activities & Clubs </a></li>
      <li><a href="http://abasynisb.edu.pk/pdf/Handbook-final-draft.pdf"> Student Handbook</a></li>
      <li><a href="community.php"> Community Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="student_schedules.php"> Student Schedules </a></li>
      <li><a href="digital_library.php"> Digital Library </a></li>
      <li><a href=""> Learning Management System </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle list-bold" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Center of M & E
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">About the Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">OBE at AUIC</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Software System - TLS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> Research and Analysis</a></li>

            </ul>
  </li>
        </ul>
</div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You should put explanation for the solution, not just code.

Comment: there were missing closing tags in the code:- <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"> this tag wasn't closed,<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> these two tags were also not closed at the right place.